# Need fo get the domain from which the user landing to my website?

Tags: javascript, django

I am sharing one url link in different social media platforms. I need to find from which domain the user has landed to my website page. is there any possible way for finding the base url of social media plotforms.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the referer header https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters to URL. Something like [www.example.com?source=facebook](http://www.example.com?source=facebook) etc., change the parameter before sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

This can be found from the documentation regarding META attribute from the HTTP Request [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META).

To access this in a template you can do so like:

```
{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}
```

You could create a link back to something like:

```
<a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">PAGE FROM REFERRER</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with an optional “sites” framework. using site we can get domain name  from request which the user landing to my website?

```
django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
current_site = get_current_site(request)
domain_name = current_site.domain
```

[Django site Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites)